# Delayed repetition of an event using Web Worker

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, microsoft-edge, web-worker

I have few CPU intensive tasks to be performed on my web page which involve some calculations and drawing of texts. These tasks are supposed to be repeated at an interval (10-20 ms).

I decided to use Web Worker for this job, considering our target browsers are latest versions of major browsers which supports HTML5 & Web Worker.

The content of `draw_worker.js` is something like in standard format:

```
var i = 0;

function timedCount() {
    i = i + 1;
    postMessage(i);
    setTimeout("timedCount()", 15);
}

timedCount();
```

The content of function used by Worker is:

```
function startWorker() {
    if(typeof(Worker) !== "undefined") {
        if(typeof(w) == "undefined") {
            w = new Worker("draw_worker.js");
        }
        w.onmessage = function(event) {
            //Function to calculate & draw
            calculateDrawData();
        };
    }

}
```

Things work fine on all major browsers on PC and Tablets without any issues. The `calculateDrawData()` function is called at around 15-20 ms interval as I expect. But on few Tablets and phones things are not smooth. I investigated and found that `calculateDrawData()` is not called at interval of around 15 ms and very frequently it takes up 70 ms or more before it is called.

I doubted that execution of `calculateDrawData()` function might be taking long time. But after investigation found that `calculateDrawData()` takes only 6-12 ms.

I'm just wondering what might be causing delay in interval at which `onmessage` is being called. How to investigate it further?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I kept on working on this problem as I had no other choice after receiving no response at SO. The `Developer tools` available in Chrome helped me in digging out root-cause. The "Performance" profiling was right tool to help in such cases. I selected `Perfromance` tab in DevTools. The steps taken afterwards to analyse problem are:

1. Select `CPU throttling` to "5 x slowdown".
2. Record for about 20 seconds.
3. Review analysis results.
4. The prime area of attention were wider columns in `Main` section as those exhibits functions take longer time to execute.
5. Selected one of wider column. The `Summary` tab showed details of time distribution. Then selected `Bottoms-Up` table for analysis of time taken by every function and sub-functions.

The top level function was being called from a `setInterval` call.

The function pointed out by `Bottom-Up` section was taking about 70% of Total execution time.

The task was rather simple afterwards. The function in question had to be optimized.

The main point I want to raise here is that since un-optimized function was called from `setInterval` it was able to interfere with `Web Worker` and was even able to delay it.